# Setup Replication on two database on different domain

Tags: replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have two servers.i Want to setup Replication( Transactional publication ) between the two servers.The servers are on  different domain.
After Going through the configuration for Distributor,Publisher and Subscriber.

I View the Syncronization status and start the snapshot agent.
 It ran up to 100% and then stop.I click on the monitor replication button and ViewDetails,it Show this error messages:

```
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'Mydomain\myusername'. (Source:  MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)
```

Viewing the Syncronization on the subcriber display another error
It says:

```
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'mydomain\username'.
```

Could it be that replication cannot be setup on databases on two different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the replication agent process account does not have the required permissions and/or you are trying to replicate across untrusted domains.

Replication across non-trusted domains or workgroups can be done using Windows Authentication by configuring **pass-through authentication**.

Create a local Windows account on both the Publisher and Subscriber that has the same username and password. Use this account for the replication agent process account and have the connections to the publisher, distributor, and/or subscriber impersonate this account. Ensure the account has the permissions required in [Replication Agent Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

This approach is covered in the section ***Use Windows Authentication to Set Up Replication Between Two Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains*** in [HOW TO: Replicate Between Computers Running SQL Server in Non-Trusted Domains or Across the Internet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321822).